# Can I include *.xslt in ASP.NET class library for internal use?

Tags: asp.net, xslt

I want to use same xsl template in few websites. Can I add it into class library? If yes how can I Load it? Example of path, etc...

Comment: I've edited your tags because this is not general XSLT questions but asp.net library question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, check out this article:
http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000653.html

I've written an [embedded resource resolver](https://github.com/maxtoroq/myxsl.net/blob/master/myxsl.net/XmlEmbeddedResourceResolver.cs) that resolves URLs like this:

```
clires://assembly-name/path-to-embedded-file/embedded-file.xsl
```

Comment: Look's fine. But I'm receiving exception like "XmlResolver returned null..." (( path seems to be correct...

Comment: Are you passing the resolver when you call XslCompiledTrasform.Load ?

Comment: yep. And xsl-file build-action property is embedded-resource.    XmlEmbeddedResourceResolver resolver = new XmlEmbeddedResourceResolver();
xslt.Load("clires://RzhdOnline/xsl/eticket_mail.xsl", XsltSettings.TrustedXslt, resolver);

Comment: @pukipuki: I'm not sure if XslCompiledTrasform uses the resolver for the principal stylesheet, I think only for imports. I suggest you debug and hit a breakpoint in the GetEntity method of the resolver, or you could just call Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("RzhdOnline.xsl.eticket_mail.xsl")

Comment: The problem is in case sensitivity... lib's name has been translated into lower case in GetEntity method )

Comment: @pukipuki: You can also omit the host delimiter if the resource is in the calling assembly, try clires:RzhdOnline/xsl/eticket_mail.xsl

Comment: @pukipuki: Or set `resolver.DefaultAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`